# how do i change the file attributes?

Tags: indexing, file-attributes

I am using the the GetFileAttributes() function in my code. Its return the value as 0x2010. Because, Its saying, "FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NOT_CONTENT_INDEXED". I need output as 0x10.
Please help me to resolve this. I am using empty folder to get file attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output *is* `0x10`. I.e., it's `0x2000` which means FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NOT_CONTENT_INDEXED and it's also `0x10` which means FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY. The values are bitwise-or'ed together. You can test them like this:

```
if (file_attr & 0x10)
  puts("FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY");
```

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. If the file is not content-indexed then that flag will be set. Just reset it if you want (subtracting 0x2000 is perhaps the conceptually simplest way).

Comment: Then, How do I make that folder as content indexed.

Comment: That way madness lies. Why do you think you need to do that?

Comment: After getting the result as 0x2010 then change that value.I think, this not a correct solution for making the file to be content indexed. I want to make the file as content indexed. I don't know, what wrong in this. Is making the file or folder as content indexed is wrong thing?. In simple way, i am expecting, the file or folder shouldn't contain the attribute "FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NOT_CONTENT_INDEXED".

Comment: @user3440628, Your original question implied nothing about your desire to content-index your files. I'm not sure how to get that done, but one possibility is to do a disk-wide search for a file that doesn't exist. That should reach every file and folder, and it might also content-index them for faster searching next time.